# cant access Key.isDown

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, keyboard

so when I run the below script it says in compiler errors
"Access of undefined property Key"
I'm working off of a tutorial but trying to recreate it myself. If I bring the source from the tutorial into flash the script runs fine no problems. Do I need to define or import Key somehow? I assumed it was a built in thing like Stage.height

```
function runGame():void{
    if(Key.isDown(Key.UP) || Key.isDown(87)){
        if(velocityY<velocityYMax){
            velocityY+=acceleration;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to tag the question with the language used.

Comment: Your tutorial was probably AS2. http://lassieadventurestudio.wordpress.com/2008/09/03/as3-key-isdown-behavior/

Comment: (incidentally, that was the second result in a search for "as3 Key"...)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Import!

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
```